# Express not successfully uploaded in heroku

Tags: express, heroku

So I am trying to upload an Express app in Heroku. This is [it](https://github.com/theo82/iLoveAristi-api).

After typing `git push heroku master` I get this on the terminal

```
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
remote:     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
remote:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
remote:     at startup (node.js:129:16)
remote:     at node.js:814:3
remote: /tmp/build_a71d340b/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
remote:       var notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
remote:                                                     ^
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
remote:     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
remote:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
remote:     at startup (node.js:129:16)
remote:     at node.js:814:3
remote: /tmp/build_a71d340b/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
remote:       var notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
remote:                                                     ^
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
remote:     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
remote:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
remote:     at startup (node.js:129:16)
remote:     at node.js:814:3
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ilovearisti-api.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ilovearisti-api.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ilovearisti-api.git'
```

I really don't know where this

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

is coming from.

How can I upload the app in heroku without any errors?

Comment: Check your syntax, you might have an extra }

Comment: the app is running file locally. If there was an error, it wouldn't run in localhost